# Base class of controls that have a text property?

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to make a picker model which inherits from UIPickerViewModel (I'll clarify that I am new to iOS development with Xamarin) that takes a control parameter in its constructor, in which it will display the picked element.

I want to be able to pass either a text field or a label without creating two different models for each. Is there a base class I could use instead of the concrete object that includes the Text property?

This is my current model class:

```
using System;
using TCPClient.TCP;
using UIKit;

namespace TCPClient.Models
{
    public class EncodingPickerModel : UIPickerViewModel
    {
        private readonly UITextField _targetControl;

        public EncodingPickerModel(UITextField targetControl)
        {
            _targetControl = targetControl;
        }

        public override nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView pickerView)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
        {
            return Enum.GetNames(typeof(EncodingType)).Length;
        }

        public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
        {
            if (component == 0) return row.ToString();
            return ((EncodingType)Convert.ToInt32(row)).ToString("F");
        }

        public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
        {
            _targetControl.Text = ((EncodingType)Convert.ToInt32(row)).ToString("F");            
        }
    }
}
```

What I wish to do is UITextField _targetControl with a generic object that does have a Text property but I don't know which one is the base object. UIControl doesn't really have a text property.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Apple Docs : `@interface UITextField : UIControl` , `@interface UILabel : UIView`

Comment: Why don't you have multiple constructors.  One that take a string and the other that take a label.

Comment: @jdweng Because then I would have to have 2 private member variables, one of which would have to be null if only one control is needed.

Comment: No. You only need one private variable for the text.  The one that gets the label reads the text in the label and sets the private variable for the text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing in a specific control, you can accept an `Action<EncodingType>` that returns back the `EncodingType` that is selected. This way the consumer can decide what needs to be done with the selected value and allows the `EncodingPickerModel` to be flexible for any control:

```
public class EncodingPickerModel : UIPickerViewModel
{
    private readonly Action<EncodingType> _onItemSelected;

    public EncodingPickerModel(Action<EncodingType> onItemSelected)
    {
        _onItemSelected = onItemSelected;
    }

    public override nint GetComponentCount(UIPickerView pickerView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override nint GetRowsInComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, nint component)
    {
        return Enum.GetNames(typeof(EncodingType)).Length;
    }

    public override string GetTitle(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        if (component == 0) return row.ToString();
        return ((EncodingType)Convert.ToInt32(row)).ToString("F");
    }

    public override void Selected(UIPickerView pickerView, nint row, nint component)
    {
        var encodingType = ((EncodingType)Convert.ToInt32(row)); 

        _onItemSelected.Invoke(encodingType);

    }
}

//usage:

myPicker.Model = new EncodingPickerModel(OnEncodingTypeSelected)

private void OnEncodingTypeSelected(EncodingType encType)
{
    //do stuff like setting text property on label or textview, etc.
}
```

Comment: That's an answer that absolutely solves my problem, thank you.